# Magento 2 checkout - move Shipping methods block

Tags: magento2

I am trying to move the Shipping methods block higher up the page of the onepagecheckout.

[image: magento 2 checkout move shipping method block]

I have tried using the "displayArea" item to move it but it didn't work.

```
<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">customer-email</item>
```

I can't even see anywhere in the checkout_index_index.xml that references this block to render.

I have also tried moving it within the shipping.html file. After publishing static content and clearing cache nothing changed.

Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the shipping.html was being overridden by a third party module...

Comment: Please mark the question as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge :)